# Upgrade MVCMembership to 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know if there is a version of [MVCMembership](http://www.codeplex.com/mvcmembership) that works with MVC 1.0?

The existing code doesn't work properly with this release. Alternatively, would anyone be willing to help upgrade the code-base?

(**edit** to draw out the key points)

Comment: I'll do it for five hundie upfront.

Comment: It's a question and a request :)

Comment: You might want to actually post this in the discussion on the wiki site that the project is stored on.

Comment: Yeah I have tried to contact the project creators to know avail ? I wouldn't have even put this here, but I don't know the previous version iterations.

Comment: Hi Tom,

I am currently working on this and hope to have a release out soon. If you check the source trunk at codeplex, you'll see a vresion that works with RTM (which will work with 1.0), though it is not yet fully-featured (and is quite different than previous releases).

Contact me for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the creator of the MvcMembership project and I am addressing this concern on the project website:

http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=52251

Please close this question as I think it is indeed more appropriately addressed on CodePlex.

Troy